# mklink - subfolders named with non-ASCII characters are inaccessible

Tags: windows-10, mklink

I've used `mklink` to create a a directory symbolic link to a network drive:

`mklink /d "music" "\\192.168.2.1\mybook\music\"`

This works fine.

However, when trying to access sub-folders via that link which have special characters in their names (such as 'à', 'ò', 'í', 'é' or Hebrew characters) the sub-folders are inaccessible and Windows explorer shows a "location is not available error", whereas other sibling sub-folders with an all ASCII name work just fine.

Accessing these problematic folders via the network share itself works as well.

Is this expected? Is there a limitation I'm not aware of? 
Anyway around this issue?

Edited to add: here's an example of a problematic directory name:

`Air (1997) - Premiers Symptômes`

Comment: To be clear here, are those problematic "special characters" normally considered valid for a filename?

Comment: Also, "accessing" = windows explorer, 3rd party/other software?

Comment: @yorik, yes, they're fine. See added directory name example. As for accessing, Windows Explorer fails opening the directory with the error mentioned above and other software fails as well (e.g., foobar2000 produces a "Location not parsable" error).

Comment: NTFS purportedly supports unicode for filenames (based on the current codepage?), and there are certain windows API calls that have unicode-aware and non-unicode versions (CreateSymbolicLinkW). Is your network share a samba share? The network share may be reporting with e.g. "testÃ©" instead of "testé".

Comment: @Yorik, the network share is via ddwrt's NAS functionality. I don't think that samba is used in this case. But not using the router as a NAS is certainly an options if all else fails.

Comment: @Yorik, err, not sure what I was thinking. The share is fine via the network path. It is only via the symbolic link that the issue occurs.

Comment: I am 75% certain ddwrt uses Samba for file shares. I am not well-versed in code-pages and encoding problems, but I know that samba has two configuration settings called `iocharset` and `codepage`, and that one is for the server and one is for reporting to the client. I suspect you may be seeing one charset via the mklink and a different one via a normal browse of the share. Unclear to me if this is configurable on a ddwrt install. See, for instance ( http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/samba-special-character-umlaute-garbled-136433/ ).